# Effect of Multiple TADOConnection

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe2

What is the effect of multiple tadoconnection? 
Here is what I did :

1. I put a TADOConnection to almost every form in my application.
2. Those TADOConnection will connect to the database(MySQL) everytime  I create an instance of a form.

In an average use of the application, about 15 forms will be used(15 tadoconnections connected to the database). So far my application is running smooth. But yesterday, a user complained of an error "MySQL has gone away".
I've encountered that error in the past and it was because the data is too large, or hardware problem. But today, the data is not big and the hardware is in excellent condition. By the way, the connection is local. Does the multiple tadoconnection produced the error?

---

Comment: 1) That error message sounds custom, I doubt it comes from the ADO Connection, 2) You should never have to create multiple ADO Connection components - just 1 per thread. So if you don't use multi-threading, you should only have one connection.

Comment: 1. The error is not custom, their are other text but the main error message is mysql has gone away. 2. We've been using multiple tadoconnection because it has already been practiced doing so, it's like 1 tadoconnection or multiple tadoconnection is just the same. If we are going to make it only 1 tadoconnection(because our apps are not threaded) then I need a valid reason, I need to know what exactly is the effect of multiple tadoconnection, because there are so many corrections if we are going to correct it..

Comment: Someone else will surely give a better explanation than me, but the main problem is the initial connection. In your environment, you might not experience issues with initial connection, but in other environments (such as a slow DNS lookup and many others) that initial connection might take many seconds or even minutes. I myself faced this problem doing exactly as you are, and resolved it by only using one. Plus, managing one connection from one place is much easier than one for each form. Imagine 5 years from now when you wind up with 30 forms and a large database.

Comment: Well I've never used MySQL but have confirmed it appears to be a real error message. However a very awkward error message that I would never expect.

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/27/mysql-limitations-part-4-one-thread-per-connection/  and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20479/how-to-resolve-too-many-connections-and-fatal-error-in-mysql-running-on-vps

Comment: Good gaad I laughed at this "Imagine 5 years from now when you wind up with 30 forms and a large database".. HAHA, Thanks for the info :D

Answer (score 1):

The effect of multiple ADOConnections is that you, open multiple independent Session in the Database. I wouldnt recommend your solution, in consideration of Transactionmanagement and table locking

Server has gone away: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html

Comment: "MySQL server has gone away". Decided to go looking for greener pastures.